# Power with complex exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, complex-numbers

I want to demonstrate that $i ^ i =  \mp 1$

$i^i=i^i$

$(i^i)^i=i^{-1}$

$(i^i)^i = -i$

$((i^i)^i)^i=(-i)^i$

$i^{-i}=(-1)^i \cdot i^i$

$\frac{1}{i^i}=(i^2)^i \cdot i^i$

$1=i^{2i} \cdot i^i \cdot i^i$

$1=i^{4i}$

$i^i = \mp 1$

But $ i ^ i = e ^{\frac{- \pi} {2}} $

What is wrong?

Comment: The way you post your question is wrong. You are supposed to make clear what your question exactly is, and show some of your own thoughts on the question.

Comment: After the edit, the question now makes sense!

Comment: $i^i$ is **definitely** not $\mp 1$.  It's actually a multi-valued complex function whose principal value is $e^{-i \pi/2}$.

Comment: @bjcolby15 How many values in exact? For a fourth degree equation has 4 roots. So does an equation of degree i have '' i '' roots?

Comment: No, because it is derived using $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$, and because sine and cosine are periodic, $i^i$ has infinitely many roots (periodically)

Comment: What do you mean? You can say $0$ and $2\pi$ "represent" the same thing, but you can't say $0=2\pi=6.28...$

Comment: You're performing operations that don't always make sense in this context. It's not surprising you cab prove some nonsense. Moreover, complex powers of negative and complex quantities are in general *not* single-valued.

Comment: @EsposaDoYoongi The general solution to $i^i$ is $e^{-\pi /2 + \pi k}$, but the principal value (when $k=0$) is $e^{-\pi/2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simplified version of your dilemma is that
$$(i^i)^4 \neq (i^4)^i \iff e^{-2\pi + 8k\pi} \neq 1$$
even though they both "look" like $i^{4i}$. 
Exponent laws are reserved for real quantities: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentLaws.html

Answer (score 2):

BEFORE you start demonstrating a theorem about
$\,\imath^\imath,\,$ you have to DEFINE it.

What is your definition of $\,\imath^\imath\,?$